# Copy And Paste Function Not working on PHP Echo

Tags: javascript, php

I made a copy and paste functionality and here it is

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
    if (document.selection) {
      var range = document.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
      range.select().createTextRange();
      document.execCommand("copy");

    } else if (window.getSelection) {
      var range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
      window.getSelection().addRange(range);
      document.execCommand("copy");
      alert("text copied, copy in the text-area")
    }
  }
</script>
```

and on my html

```html
<strong>Referral Link: </strong>
<div id="div1"><?php echo $investors[0]['referal_code'];?></div>
<button class="btn" id="copy" onclick="CopyToClipboard('div1')"><i class="la la-copy"></i></button>
```

The problem is that I cant copy the value of the `echo`
but when I tried to change what inside of my div like `asdasd` it copies successfully

why is that?

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($investors[0]);`?

Comment: What is `asdasd` ?

Comment: Is that div invisible? Or can you see the result of the `echo` call?

Comment: @LukaszFormela its dynamic value now the value is `zAsd21fg`

Comment: yes I can see the result of the echo call @ChrisG

Comment: @executable its just a sample data

Comment: What I wanted to know is what's the type of the `zAsd21fg` value - var_dump() would show you this. Is it just a string?

Comment: The fact you echoed it should make no difference at all. By the time it reaches the browser it's just text. JavaScript doesn't know how it got there. Assuming the text is actually finding its way into the div then something doesn't quite add up

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: @LukaszFormela yes it is just a string

Comment: The clipboard code works fine for me on Firefox. There's no error here. Whatever the div contains will end up in the clipboard. If it works with `asdasd`, then it will work with `zAsd21fg`. Double-check again please.

Comment: @ChrisG it works when i paste using mouse but not working when using ctrl + v

Comment: Where are you trying to paste it? Also, if mouse vs. Ctrl+V makes a difference, the question seems to be a very different one now, and completely unrelated to PHP.